# Micronaut Read Timeout with HttpClient

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

I'm struggling to use the ***Micronaut HTTPClient*** for multiple calls to a third-party REST service without receiving a ***io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException***

To remove the third-party dependency, the problem can be reproduced using a simple Micronaut app calling it's own service.

Example Controller:

```
@Controller("/")
public class TestController {
      
    @Inject
    private TestClient client;

    @Get("service")
    String service() {
        return "Hello World Service";
    }
    @Get("mproxy")
    String multiproxy() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            sb.append(client.getService());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    @Get("proxy")
    String proxy() {
        return client.getService();
    }  
}
```

Test Client:

```
@Client("http://localhost:8080")
public interface TestClient {
    
    @Get("/service")
    String getService();

}
```

Calling the /service end-point directly from using curl, ab or postman produces no errors.

Calling the /mproxy end-point will throw an exception

```
ERROR i.m.r.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor - Type [clienttest.TestClient$Intercepted] executed with error: Read Timeout
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Read Timeout
        at io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.<clinit>(ReadTimeoutException.java:26)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$12.exceptionCaught(DefaultHttpClient.java:2316)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:424)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:145)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:231)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.readTimedOut(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:98)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.channelIdle(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:90)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$ReaderIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:504)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AbstractIdleTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:476)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Alternatively, the same exception is thrown if the /proxy endpoint is tested via ab

ab -c 5 -n 200 localhost:8080/proxy

or via mulitple calls with postman.

This is for micronaut version 2.5.5 with an absolutely vanilla template app, no connection-pooling or time-outs specified in application.yml.

It appears to error after 4 connections/clients but changing connection-pooling and timeouts seems to not change the result. Am I missing some client config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't going to throw an exception then I don't know what is going to.

This is caused by using `blocking` code within `Netty's event loop`.

The code over here is making a blocking request 20 times in a row which cause
the machine to break. I don't know what data is coming from the client but I would never recommend to do it in this manner.

```
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        sb.append(client.getService());
    }
```

Key message: `don't block the event loop`

To solve this what you can do is make your request `Asynchronous`. To do this
make use of `RxJava`. RxJava allows you to perform the operations in asynchronous manner. It provides you some very useful observables and operators.

The only other way: Run this operator on another thread so, that the main thread doesn't get blocked but this may not work very efficiently and still cause problem.

To get start with RxJava follow the link: https://factoryhr.medium.com/understanding-java-rxjava-for-beginners-5eacb8de12ca

Micronaut Tutorial Reactive: https://piotrminkowski.com/2019/11/12/micronaut-tutorial-reactive/

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look at that. But, I think I'd still have a problem with this test ab -c 5 -n 200 localhost:8080/proxy which doesn't call that loop at all (the loop was just an illustrative way to generate the exception). With this call (ab -c 5 -n 200 localhost:8080/proxy) to the proxy endpoint, the httpclient is only being used once per call but the exception is still thrown

Comment: You can also implement the same test with Single<String> from the service endpoint and still see the same exception if calling the proxy endpoint four times in quick succesion

Comment: You need to make sure the declarative client which is making the request to the 3 party apis must also return a reactive type. Give me you project link I'll see what's wrong :)

Comment: But here the exception is coming from DefaultHttpClient. I too am facing the same issue with blocking client, especially it gets close again and again. I am still looking into it but this is little tricky to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Update to accepted answer above, just to provide examples of working code. There are two options to not block the event-loop - use Reactive return types or execute the proxy endpoint on a different thread loop - example:

```
@Controller("/")
public class TestController {
   
    
    @Inject
    private TestClient client;

    @Inject
    private RXTestClient rxclient;

    @Get("rxservice")
    Single<String> rxservice() {
        return Single.just("Hello World Service");
    }
    @Get("service")
    String service() {
        return "Hello World Service";
    }

   
    @Get("rxproxy")
    Single<String> rxproxy() {
        return rxclient.getService();
    }
   
    @ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)
    @Get("proxy")
    String proxy() {
        return client.getService();
    }
}
```